# an application of the Borel-cantelli lemma (stuck in the proof)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

i'm reading from this page https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/02%3A_Probability_Spaces/2.06%3A_Convergence

Using the first and second Borel-Cantelli lemma i want to show that:

for any $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset ]0,1[$

$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i \gt 0 \text{ if and only if } \sum_{i=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \lt \infty$$

let $(A_i)_i$ be a sequence of independent events such that $p_i=p(A_i)$

i supposed that $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \lt \infty$ and wanted to show $\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i \gt 0 $

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \lt \infty $

$ \equiv \sum_{i=1}^\infty p(A_i^c) \lt \infty $

$\Rightarrow P\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_i^c\right) = 0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\bigcup_{i=n}^\infty A_i^c\right)=0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left((\bigcap_{i = n}^\infty A_i\right)^c)=0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}( 1-P \left(\bigcap_{i = n}^\infty A_i\right))=0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left(\bigcap_{i = n}^\infty A_i\right)=1$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = n}^\infty P_i =1$

how can i find the result

Answer (score 0):

If $\prod_{i=1}^\infty  p_i=0$ then $ \prod_{i = n}^\infty p_i =0$ for every $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = n}^\infty 
p_i=0$, a contradiction to what you have proved. Hence, $\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i \gt 0$.

The converse part follows by the same method using the second part of Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: I got it, thank you